# How to develop for SharePoint 2013 on VS 2012

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, web-application, development-enviroment

I am new in sharepoint platform. To prepare my development pc for sharepoint development I  have installed sharepoint server 2013 ,vs2012 ,sql server 2008 r2. I start reading book **“Beginning SharePoint 2013 Development”** by Steve Fox,Chris Johnson .From the book I learned vs2012 contain sharepoint option like the bellow picture.

[image]

But my vs has no sharepoint2013 option just has sharepoint2010 option like the bellow picture.more over click on sharepoint 2010 show me error.**”Sharepoint is not installed”**

[image]

What to do ? How to enable this sharepoint 2013 option in my vs?

If have any query please ask. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/03/04/now-available-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx

This will add missing project templates to VS 2012.